# Addthis difficulties on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Ok, I have a couple of questions regarding my wordpress (self-hosted) site...

**1)** The googleplus button does not appear for Addthis Smart Layers.  The following code is in my header, and you'll notice on my page only 4 buttons are shown - the Google one is missing.  It shows up at the top right of the page, but not in the floating square buttons on the left.

```
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers BEGIN -->
<!-- Go to http://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers to customize -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-522604194e450f3a"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  addthis.layers({
    'theme' : 'transparent',
    'share' : {
      'position' : 'left',
      'numPreferredServices' : 5
    }, 
    'follow' : {
      'services' : [
        {'service': 'twitter', 'id': 'TechPatrolEU'},
        {'service': 'google_follow', 'id': '104529152038746167497'},
        {'service': 'pinterest', 'id': 'techp'},
        {'service': 'tumblr', 'id': 'techpatroleu'},
        {'service': 'rss', 'id': 'http://techpatrol.eu/feed'}
      ]
    },  
    'whatsnext' : {}  
  });
</script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
```

**2)** I'm using the Smartlayers Share Plugin for wordpress.  Again, there's no +1 button for google plus, I'd also like to display more sites than just facebook twitter and pinterest.  Can anyone give me an example of the code I'd need to put in the custom button box please?  I've tried a couple of times myself but seem to be doing something wrong.  I'd like the same style buttons with counters.

**3)** Again the smartlayers plugin.  If I tick the box to show in the options to display in Excerpts, so that they show up in the list of posts on the homepage (I have excerpts turned off atm) it ruins the text wrapping around the thumbnail and all the excerpt text then appears below the image making the page look very messy.  Is there a way to fix this please?

Thanks for all your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm seeing all 5 follow buttons, including Google+. Are you still seeing this issue? If so, what browser are you using?

2) Please send me the existing code you're using and I'll be happy to modify it for you.

3) I went to your homepage, but I'm not seeing this behavior. Have you disabled this feature from the homepage?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the help!  I did post a reply on the addthis forum, but it's either awaiting moderation, or it just got deleted!

I'm sorry, I seem to have gotten a bit mixed up in my first post. My main concern is the missing plus one button from the top and bottom of my posts.  I said that this was smartlayers, but it's not it's the addthis share plugin for wordpress.  There isn't currently any code that I've used, I just select the options in the wordpress plugin settings.  Do you know why the Google plus button isn't showing please?  There looks like a gap where is should be...